# how to achieve dynamic polymorphism without extending a class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

I was asked in an interview how you can achieve dynamic polymorphism without extending a class.  How can this be done?

Comment: polymorphism without extending a class or polymorphism without inheritance ?

Comment: polymorphism without inheritance is not possible in Java

Comment: @yegor256 that's what Interfaces do

Comment: @MattWhipple - and interfaces do it through inheritance.  In Java, `extends` and `implements` are both forms of inheritance in the broad sense.

Comment: Sorry I was concerned more with the question rather than the ensuing argument over semantics.

Answer (score 40):

[Decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that exploits [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) is what you're looking for.

Polymorphism through inheritance:

```
class Cat {
  void meow() {
    // meow...
  }
}
class Lion extends Cat {
}
```

Polymorphism through encapsulation (Decorator pattern):

```
interface Cat {
  void meow();      
}
class Lion implements Cat {
  private Cat cat;
  void meow() {
    this.cat.meow();
  }
}
```

ps. More about decorators: http://www.yegor256.com/2015/02/26/composable-decorators.html

Comment: In your comment to the OP, you state, _polymorphism without inheritance is not possible in Java_, yet here you give an example of polymorphism through encapsulation. Does this example contradict the previous statement?

Answer (score 30):

The simple solution is to write a class that implements an interface rather than extending a base class.

Another solution is to create a dynamic proxy ... which is essentially a clever way of implementing an interface without explicitly writing the class.  See the [`Proxy` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) for details.

And yes, these are (or can be) examples of the decorator pattern, though the key thing here is the implementation techniques rather than the design pattern.

Answer (score 3):

According to my experience, in most job interviews the questions do not look for way too elaborate answers, and most of the times are just tricky questions, so if they asked specifically for polymorphism without extending a class, then I would say:

**Yes, you can have dynamic polymorphism by implementing an interface rather than extending a class**

then if they would ask for more options then it would be ok to bring up proxies, patterns or something else.

Hope it helps!

Comment: A good interviewer will be trying to find out 1) how much you know, and 2) whether you know how to pick an appropriate solution, and 3) whether you can communicate well.  So yes, the right way to answer this would be to offer the simple solution, and *hint* that there are other solutions, and related design patterns.  A "long and fulsome" answer where a short answer is required/expected shows poor communication skills (IMO).

Comment: But I should add that I read this Question as asking for technical information, not for advice on what to say in an interview context.

Comment: 'A "long and fulsome" answer where a short answer is required/expected shows poor communication skills (IMO).'; or a lack of knowledge, yes? And that difference is important (IMO). It may be the case that it costs more money to the company to increase someone's communication skills than to teach them some java design pattern.

Comment: @claytontstanley - I think there two cases: 1) a long and coherent, but way too detailed answer, and 2) a long and incoherent answer.  The first suggests poor communication skills, the second also suggests lack of knowledge and willingness to bluff the interviewer.  None of these are good signs.